# Dynamically aligning :after according to parent length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/VpW5x/1141/

```
.one-line {
  position: relative;
}

.one-line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25px;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
    left: 100%;
}
```

How to make the right arrow appear after the text, even if the text is really long like in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this css will help you

```
          .one-line {
               position: relative;
               display:inline-block;
               vertical-align:top;  
                 }

            .one-line:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 25px;
            background: red;
            clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
            left: 100%;
            }
```